# show/hide div on slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a slide mechanic that's working, but I am having problems getting the div class of nfooter to hide when the slide mechanic triggers.  The slide is triggered when the user clicks on the img src question.png.

I would like for the nfooter (which is another image) to disappear when the user selects the question.png image.  When the user selects the question.png image for the second time, the slide mechanic hides and the nfooter shows.

Again, the slide mechanic is working fine, I just can't get the nfooter and the question.png to play nice.

```
<pre>
<script type="text/javascript">

    // When the DOM is ready, initialize the scripts.
    jQuery(function( $ ){

    // Get a reference to the container.
    var container = $( ".container" );


    // Bind the link to toggle the slide.
    $( "a" ).click(
    function( event ){
    // Prevent the default event.
    event.preventDefault();

    // Toggle the slide based on its current
    // visibility.
    if (container.is( ":visible" )){

    // Hide - slide up.
    container.slideUp( 300 );

    } else {

    // Show - slide down.
    container.slideDown( 300 );

    }
    }
    );

    });

    </script>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"></head>

<body>
<a href="#"><img src="../question.png" /></a>
<div class="nfooter"></div>

<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src='swipe.js'></script>

<div class='container'>
<div class='inner'>
    </div>
    </div>
</pre>
```

Comment: How about making a fiddle showing your problem.

Comment: an observation: you should move your `<script>` tags either to the head section or to the end of body

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried to simply hide and show it:

```
if (container.is( ":visible" )){
    // Hide - slide up.
    container.slideUp(300, function(){ $('.nfooter').show(); });
}
else 
{
    // Show - slide down.
    container.slideDown(300, function(){ $('.nfooter').hide(); });
}
```

Comment: I have been working on this all day literally, and those two lines of code fixed it.  Thank you very much!

Comment: is there anyway I could add some timed element to control when the nfooter re-appears.  If I could have the question.png fully hide before the nfooter reappears, that would be ideal.

Answer (score 0):

Another version

```
// When the DOM is ready, initialize the scripts.
jQuery(function($) {
    // Get a reference to the container.
    var container = $(".container"), nfooter = $('.nfooter');
    // Bind the link to toggle the slide.
    $("a").click(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();

        var visibility = container.is(':visible');
        container.slideToggle(300);
        nfooter.toggle(visibility)
    });
});
```

Comment: When I tried this version, it two images appear at the same time while toggling instead of alternating.